# Compression of air layer by parallel planes

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, differential-equations

When object is falling and close to the ground "liquid pillow" appears under it. Object is of cylindrical form.

The differential equation that describes the motion is:

$$m\frac{dV}{dt} = mg - \frac{3}{2}\pi\mu V\frac{R^4}{h^3(t)}$$

where $V$ is velocity, $\mu$ is dynamic viscosity, $R$ radius of cylinder, $h$ is height, $m$ is mass.

I need to estimate time needed to reach the ground. I thought that I could solve this equation for $h(t)$ then find time when $h(t) = 0$.

I rewrote it as:

$$y''y^3 + y'\frac{3\pi R^4\mu}{2m} - gy^3 = 0$$

I tried solving this, but all my attempts failed.

Comment: How do $y$ relate to $h(t)$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev $y = h(t)$

Comment: How is the equation for $y$ obtained?

Comment: $V = y'. \frac{dV}{dt} = y''$ because velocity is first derivative of displacement, acceleration is second derivative

Comment: Then correct the typo in the equation for $y$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev where is the typo?

Comment: There should be $-gy^3$

Comment: How did you determine the friction force, from which theory?

Comment: @AlexTrounev it is Reynolds equations for lubricated layer

Comment: What are the initial and boundary conditions? From what point on the cylinder is $h(t)$ counted?